# Facebook login button android on logout do not call session.callback method

Tags: android

I am creating a small android app and added a facebook book login button. 
The problem is when I click on the login button it calls the session.callback method creates a session and everything works fine but when I click on the logout button it doesnt call the callback function again. The session variable is closed as when I bring my app from background to foreground it shows me the correct UI which I want on logging out

Here is the code snippet that I am using

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        try {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                if(!session.getPermissions().containsAll(SetPermission()))
                    session.requestNewReadPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(MainFragment.this, SetPermission()));
                CommonFacebookClass.session = session;
                m_session = session;
                SetBeforeLoginControlVIsiblity(false);
                //HideControls(false);

            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
                //HideControls(true);
                SetBeforeLoginControlVIsiblity(true);           

            } 

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Utilities.PrintMessageInConsole("NipunError" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try this : when logout button click

```
            SessionManager.clear(getApplicationContext());
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
```

and used this is session manager class :

```
     public static void clear(Context context) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Login.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I am using facebook login button.
as per this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

Comment: This is probably a temporary issue. I restarted my device and everything worked fine.